# Inserting HTML Markup in Custom Label Value

Tags: lightning-aura-components, html, xml, customlabel

I'm using Custom Labels for a specific message and I'd like to insert a link into that message, e.g., `<a href="http://my.domain.com">Go here to login</a>`.

I tried this using entity characters for rending the HTML, but that just renders it as a full string:

```
<CustomLabels>
    <labels>
        <fullName>Legal_Disclaimer_Text</fullName>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <protected>true</protected>
        <shortDescription>Legal_Disclaimer_Text</shortDescription>
        <value>You must agree to the terms of use and privacy notice below. &lt;a href='http://my.domain.com'&gt;Go here to login&lt;/a&gt;</value>
    </labels>
</CustomLabels>
```

Can HTML markup be added to Custom Labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Aura, you can do this via [aura:unescapedHtml](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:unescapedHtml/specification). This will render the text as is. Obviously, make sure you don't allow any unsafe HTML in there, because it could be a security risk. As long as the text is static, this is probably acceptable.

```
<aura:unescapedHtml value="{!$Label.c.Legal_Disclaimer_Text}" />
```

In general, you can have HTML in labels, but most language features (e.g. Visualforce) will take steps to automatically encode HTML as HTML entities to avoid injection attacks. Developers must always take specific actions in order to override this behavior.

Comment: Wow, very cool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also in LWC you can use [lightning-formatted-rich-text](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-rich-text/documentation) . For example:

```
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={label.myLabelWithHTML}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also in Visualforce you can use [apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) with the escape attribute set to false. For example:

```
<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!$Label.MyLabelContainingHTML}"/>
```