# Can you do nested labels?

Tags: customlabel

I'm trying to use a label within a lightning web component. In particular it's value is something like

```
blah blah see <a target="_blank" href={labels.ANOTHER_LABEL}>link</a> for more information
```

where we are keeping the link's address in another custom label. I can't seem to get the lightning web component to recognize {labels.ANOTHER_LABEL} as a variable, it keeps trying to call it as a string literal.

I've tried both the lightning app builder and lightning web component formats from https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cl_about.htm&type=5 and neither work (the "{") doesn't get recognized as code.

Comment: You cannot do this. You can use "mailmerge" approaches, substituting values where the "pattern" includes markers like `{0}` or `{1}`. However, embedding HTML in labels is not a good idea and certainly would not be allowed to be done in managed packages which are reviewed by Salesforce's security team since an admin could inject hacks into pages by crafting HTML that includes JavaScript. See [this other Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275376/inserting-html-markup-in-custom-label-value) for more info.

Comment: This isn't for a managed package. It's for a Salesforce Site that we made in experience builder so a hacker wont have access to the labels. Is there a better way to reference a url stored in a label from another label?

Comment: Storing URLs in labels instead of as custom settings is actually an anti-pattern unless you need different labels for different languages. You need to use something like mailmerge to combine the labels. In apex this uses `String.format`. If you want to do it in JavaScript use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/4673436#4673436). You then use `{0}` in the first label and pass the second label to the formatting function.

Comment: BTW, my point about labels and security is still valid even outside a managed package; a disgruntled admin could hide malicious code in a label that is explicitly rendered as HTML in a page.

Comment: Did you import the label in `JS` as shown here. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_labels

Comment: Yep tried that too. We are just going to hard code it. It's a project that I took over from another team. They originally used labels in this context for easy translations but our team who now owns it does not like this design. We will probably change the design in the future to use something like a proper CMS.